# Importing com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig, cannot resolve symbol, IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm doing simple web project using JEE 8.0 (no maven)
I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2.2.
Trying to import files:
`import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;`
I get error **Cannot resolve symbol 'zaxxer'**
I've seen issues where people were using Maven, but i do not use it, it's clean JEE project.
I've tried it to run as administrator or to "find JAR on the web" option, but it failed.

Also, my file structure looks like this:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBK2F.png)

I'll be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: Find a jar with this class and add it to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a [jar with this](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.zaxxer%22%20AND%20a%3A%22HikariCP%22) class and add it to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).